# How recover release configuration in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I deleted the `release` configuration mode for a visual studio 2012 c++ project accidently, how could I recover it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert need to redo the modification of the project, which is tedious.

Another solution:

1)Create a new project and open the project's vcxproj file, or just open a old revision project file.

2)Copy all the Release related xml element to the old revision file.(need to modify the include path/library path/library input etc)

done.

Answer (score 2):

Revert to a version in your source control repository before you made this change.

Comment: or close the project file without saving